# Why is text in Windows 11 search bar suddenly started to show right aligned?

Tags: taskbar, search, windows-11

My Windows 11 Search was working as expected so far, I press Alt+Esc, then start typing, and the the text was left aligned.

Now I noticed, it suddenly displays right aligned... As far as I know I did not change any setting... especially not any language related...

Is there any setting I can go for and change back the original left aligned?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a multilingual setup, e.g., Arabic, Hebrew or other RTL text?

Comment: Definitely no. Nothing RTL related is installed